# FormsAuthentication.SignOut() using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, formsauthentication

Does anyone please help me for solving this issue, In my asp.net application, i am using FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); method for sign out the application, but i have one strange requirement that i have to implement the FormsAuthentication.SignOut() by using Javascript function. Is it possible? if yes, please help me by providing the sample code to achieving this requirement.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use AJAX to "load" the page that calls FormsAuthentication.SignOut.

Using JQuery it would look something like this, given that the logout button has ID "logout".

```
$('#logout').click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/logout',
        success: function () {
            document.location = '/logged_out';
        }, error: function () { 
            alert('Logout failed');
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```